# How can I define a ReST endpoint that allows json input and maps it to a JsonSlurper

Tags: json, angularjs, rest, groovy, restangular

I want to write an API ReST endpoint, using Spring 4.0 and Groovy, such that the @RequestBody parameter can be any generic JSON input, and it will be mapped to a Groovy JsonSlurper so that I can simply access the data via the slurper.

The benefit here being that I can send various JSON documents to my endpoint without having to define a DTO object for every format that I might send.

Currently my method looks like this (and works):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.PUT, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
ResponseEntity<String> putTest(@RequestBody ExampleDTO dto) {

    def json = new groovy.json.JsonBuilder()
    json(
            id: dto.id,
            name: dto.name
    );

    return new ResponseEntity(json.content, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

But what I want, is to get rid of the "ExampleDTO" object, and just have any JSON that is passed in get mapped straight into a JsonSlurper, or something that I can input into a JsonSlurper, so that I can access the fields of the input object like so:

```
def json = new JsonSlurper().parseText(input);
String exampleName = json.name;
```

I initially thought I could just accept a String instead of ExampleDTO, and then slurp the String, but then I have been running into a plethora of issues in my AngularJS client, trying to send my JSON objects as strings to the API endpoint.  I'm met with an annoying need to escape all of the double quotes and surround the entire JSON string with double quotes.  Then I run into issues if any of my data has quotes or various special characters in it. It just doesn't seem like a clean or reliable solution.

I open to anything that will cleanly translate my AngularJS JSON objects into valid Strings, or anything I can do in the ReST method that will allow JSON input without mapping it to a specific object.

Thanks in advance!

Tonya

Comment: angular.toJson(obj, [pretty]); doesn't work for you? pretty is a boolean to maintain whitespace and newlines

Comment: That sends the data across to the API endpoint as plain JSON.  If my endpoint is expecting a string, this is rejected by Spring Rest with a 400 error, "request is syntactically incorrect".  I cannot get my endpoint to expect JSON, unless I supply some class whose fields match the JSON data; so that Spring can translate the JSON code into the object.

Comment: Have you considered just using `@RequestBody Map dto` and eliminate the JsonSlurping?

Comment: I like, and want the JSON slurping. The structure that will be incoming is too complicated to represent with a Map without causing undue code complexity.